# (codeigniter) foreach error Message: Illegal string offset

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

i want to insert "period" in some table, and i have error like :
**Message: Illegal string offset 'nm'**

i don't understand whats wrong in my script.

script:

```
if($this->input->post('save')){

$price = $this->input->post('price');
$period = $this->input->post('period');

if($product == "tshirt"){
    $gender = $this->input->post('gender');
    $model = $this->input->post('model');
    $usia = $this->input->post('usia');
    $ukuran = $this->input->post('ukuran');
    $bahan = $this->input->post('bahan');
    $warna = $this->input->post('warna');
    $ukurangambar = $this->input->post('ukurangambar');
    $metode = $this->input->post('metode');
    $stokkustom = $this->input->post('stokkustom');
}

foreach($price as $index=>$value){
    foreach($period as $value2){
        if($product == "tshirt"){
            $this->Products->delete_pricelist_apparel($product, $gender, $model, $usia, $ukuran, $bahan, $warna, $ukurangambar, $metode, $stokkustom, $index);
        }

        $arr['period'] = $value2[$index];

        if($product == "tshirt"){
            $this->Products->insert_pricelist_apparel($product, $gender, $model, $usia, $ukuran, $bahan, $warna, $ukurangambar, $metode, $stokkustom, $index, $arr);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Thanks in advance

Comment: The code you provided doesn't seem to be related to your issue. Did the error message point you to a specific line?

Comment: sorry the script shorted by me because too many script not used.
error showing in line "**$arr['period'] = $value2[$index];**"

Comment: And are you sure that all the indexes of `$price` exist in `$period`? What the error says is that you're trying to access an index in `$period` that doesn't exist. Since it is created from the POST data, it could mean  that the specific `nm` index was not submitted in the 1st place.

Comment: if i use like "**$arr['period'] = $value2;**", it work, but it inserting the same values in tables.

Comment: What is the content of each `$price` and `$period` ?

Comment: content of $price = array, 100, 200, 300. and content of $periode is array from input form value.